# Form is not giving value on controller for sql.date

Tags: java, forms, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Form is not giving value on controller for sql.date i am using spring and following is my code for form

```
 <form:input path="regDateFrom" cssClass="txt-field-date" id="txt_reg_form" readonly="true" />
```

and my controller is as.

```
 protected ModelAndView processFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {
    String param_error = null;
    VehicleSearch vehicleSampling = (VehicleSearch) command;
    System.out.println(vehicleSampling.getRegDateFrom());
```

on print it gives null

Comment: where is `@ModelAttribute` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }
```

and instead of "sql.date" use "util.date"

Also try by removing property "readonly"

Comment: Why i was asking to remove readonly attribute, as for attribute disabled="true", values are not sent with request. So just wanted to check weather values are getting passed to server or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to remove "ReadOnly=true", if readOnly is set to true, the value will not be passed along with the request.